# Parsing huge multiline zipped files with sc.textFiles in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to parse a 20GB zipped file which is in multiline format. I am trying to parse each event into exactly one line for which I am splitting the file on a regex.
When I use the following code:

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(input, 100).flatMap {
x => x._2.split(REGEX)}.map {
x => x.replaceAll("""\n""", " ")}
```

it works but as sc.wholeTextFiles gets the whole 20GB file in one place it is causing memory issues.

It tried to replace sc.wholeTextFile with sc.textFiles and have the below code:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(input, 100).flatMap {
x => x.split(REGEX)}.map {
x => x.replaceAll("""\n""", " ")}
```

However, it does not give me the similar result. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to try `hadoopFiles` and find a InputFormat class that supports the archive file format you're working with. For example, BZIP2 is well supported, Zip or Gzip, not so much. But regex splitting is not a good solution for memory usage

Comment: @cricket_007, I tried that approach as well and it worked, but since it is running on zipped file, the job is taking just 1 executors even though I specify 20 executors.

Comment: Zip files are not splittable for Hadoop formats , which would explain that